# d3 edges overlap node

Tags: d3.js

I created a network in D3.js that updates links (both remove and add) as you move the slider back and forth.

However the edges overlap the nodes (as in edges are drawn ontop of the nodes...)
I think https://github.com/agfk/knowledge-maps/issues/1 looks at the issue but I'm not quite sure what it means.

I might have something to do with the order that the lines are drawn as opposed to the nodes but I don't know how to fix that. Svgs also don't come with z-indexes so I can manipulate it through css.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Please provide more info.  A JSFiddle, some source code, perhaps screenshots.  It's difficult to tell what you're asking based on the description above.

Comment: http://s1309.beta.photobucket.com/user/zephyrwind1/media/ScreenShot2013-01-21at60222PM_zpse26a477a.png.html

this is a screencap. You can see the overlap of the edges on the nodes. I'm not quite sure why it's doing that. There is a slider that filters links based on a threshold.

Comment: Still not completely sure if I understand your issue, as I can't imagine the slider you're describing, but this link discusses how to determine the order in which elements are drawn.  In your case perhaps you want to draw the edges first and then the nodes: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/d3-js/JCXKef_GRCQ

Comment: thanks got it! just used selection.insert() and worked out :)

Comment: I will go ahead and add my comment as the answer then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link discusses how to determine the order in which elements are drawn. In your case, perhaps you want to draw the edges first and then the nodes:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/d3-js/JCXKef_GRCQ